# R: Substitute multiple unwanted variables with NAs across multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, data-wrangling

Having a tough time with some data wrangling. I am trying to keep only certain author institutional affiliations in a bibliographic data frame and replace the many unwanted affiliations with NAs. I need to do this across multiple columns since papers have multiple authors (up to 68).

reproducible code:

```
so <- data.frame(inst_1=c("FC1","FC2","Uni1","lab3","lab2"),
                 inst_2=c("FC1","FC5","college4","laboratory1","lab2"),
                 inst_3=c("FC2","FC2","University2","lab5","lab5"),
                 inst_4=c("FC3","FC6","dept2","lab3.2","lab1"),
                 inst_5=c("FC1","FC2","Uni3","labB","lab5"))
```

Example data frame:

```
 inst_1      inst_2      inst_3 inst_4 inst_5
1    FC1         FC1         FC2    FC3    FC1
2    FC2         FC5         FC2    FC6    FC2
3   Uni1    college4 University2  dept2   Uni3
4   lab3 laboratory1        lab5 lab3.2   labB
5   lab2        lab2        lab5   lab1   lab5
```

I want to select every column that has the prefix "inst" (likely using str_detect), and in those selected columns replace any institution that does **not** contain the characters "FC" with NAs. This is necessary because this sheet has 68 institution columns (inst prefix) and hundred of rows (individual scientific articles). I can't just select which institutions to replace with NAs because there are hundreds of different institutions, while I am just interested in keeping the institutions that contain "FC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) dplyr** Use mutate/across like this

```
library(dplyr)

so %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("inst"), ~ replace(., !grepl("FC", .), NA)))
```

giving:

```
  inst_1 inst_2 inst_3 inst_4 inst_5
1    FC1    FC1    FC2    FC3    FC1
2    FC2    FC5    FC2    FC6    FC2
3   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
4   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
5   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

**2) Base R** or using only base R:

```
ok <- startsWith(names(so), "inst")
repl <- function(x) replace(x, !grepl("FC", x), NA)
replace(so, ok, lapply(so[ok], repl))
```

**3) collapse** or using the collapse package with repl from (2)

```
library(collapse)

tfmv(so, startsWith(names(so), "inst"), repl)
```

**4) data.table**  With data.table we define a vector of inst names and use it with repl from (2).

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(so)
inst <- grep("^inst", names(so))
DT[, (inst) := lapply(.SD, repl), .SDcols = inst]
```